# How to solve 4 apples, 5 oranges and 6 bananas in 4 baskets?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How many ways are there to place 4 apples, 5 oranges and 6 banana into 4 indistinguishable baskets?

---

My thinking was to use stars and bars methods separately for each fruit and then multiply the totals of each to get the total number of ways.

Apples:
${4+3 \choose 3}$

Oranges:
${5+3 \choose 3}$

Banans:
${6+3 \choose 3}$

Total = ${7 \choose 3}{8 \choose 3}{9\choose 3}$

Am I right in my thinking here?

Comment: Stars and Bars would make sense if the baskets could be distinguished, but that isn't the case here.

Comment: How would you go about solving this problem then?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but it looks extremely messy to me.  I'd start with the bananas...unless I am miscounting there are $9$ ways to do them.  Now analyze each one of those $9$.  There are some symmetries that help, but it might be more trouble to sort them out then it is worth.  I don't see a quick shortcut (which doesn't mean there isn;'t one, of course).

Comment: Consider the simpler problem of $n$ apples in $m$ indistinguishable baskets. Then you are counting the number of partitions of $n$ into at most $m$ parts. Like if $n=6$ and $m=4$ then $6=3+2+1$ would mean put $3$ apples in one of the baskets, $2$ in another, $1$ in another and $0$ in the last one.

Comment: Wouldnt stars and bars also apply here then? So if $n=6$ and $m=4$ then it would be ${9\choose3}$?

Comment: Again, Stars and Bars is only relevant for distinct baskets.  For the $6$ bananas there are only $9$ ways to do it. namely $\{6,0,0,0\}, \{3,1,1,1\},\{2,2,2,0\},\{5,1,0,0\},\{4,2,0,0\},\{4,1,1,0\},\{3,2,1,0\},\{3,3,0,0\},\{2,2,1,1\}$.  Whereas $\binom 93=84$.

Comment: Note:  I listed them by symmetry.  The first three, for instance, distinguish exactly one basket.  The next three distinguish exactly two, etc.   This breakdown might help or, as I said, it might be more trouble than it is worth.

Answer (score 1):

The species formula for one non-empty basket is

$$oneBasket  = Ens_0^4 \ (A) \cdot Ens_0^5 \ (O) \cdot Ens_0^6 \ (B) -1 $$

where $E_0^k$ are sets with at most $k$ elements. A set of four non-empty baskets is:
$$Ens_4 \ (oneBasket)$$

Since the parts of a partition must be non-empty, we will have to calculate four cases, from one non-empty basket to four non-empty baskets.

After writing the cycle index we will extract some coefficients of $ \ {a^4\over 4!}{o^5\over 5!}{b^6\over 6!} \ $ for the e.g.f. and $ \ a^4o^5b^6 \ $ for the GF, the types generating function.

**1)** We write down the cycle indices of considered species $Ens_0^4(A), \ Ens_0^5(O), \ Ens_0^6(B)$

$$Z(A) = 1 + a_1 + {1 \over 2!}(a_1^2 +a_2) +... {1 \over 4!}(a_1^4+...+6a_4)  $$

$$Z(B) = 1 + b_1 + {1 \over 2!}(b_1^2 +b_2) +... {1 \over 5!}(b_1^5+...+24b_5)  $$

$$Z(C) = 1 + c_1 + {1 \over 2!}(c_1^2 +c_2) +... {1 \over 6!}(c_1^6+...+120c_6)  $$

No further symmetric cycle indices are needed.

**2)** Then the cycle index of one non-empty basket is:

$$basket (a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4;\ b_1,b_2,...,b_5;\ c_1,c_2,...,c_6) = Z(A)Z(B)Z(C) - 1$$

**3)** in order to make a "plethystic substitution" we need the ingredients :

$$basket _2 = basket \ (a_2, a_4, 0, 0 \ ; \  b_2, b_4, 0, 0, 0\ ; \  c_2, c_4, c_6,0,0,0)$$

$$basket _3 = basket \ (a_3, 0, 0, 0\ ; \  b_3, 0, 0, 0, 0\ ; \  c_3, c_6, 0,0,0,0)$$

$$basket _4 = basket \ (a_4, 0, 0, 0\ ; \  b_4, 0, 0, 0, 0 \ ; \  c_4, 0, 0,0,0,0)$$

**4)** In the cycle index of $Ens_4$

$$ {1 \over 24}(X_1^4 +  6X_1^2X_2 + 3X_2^2 + 8X_1X_3+ 6X_4)$$

we replace $X1, \ X2, \ X3, \ X4 \ $ with $ \ basket , \ basket _2, \  basket _3, \ basket _4$

**5)** now we can extract information from the cycle index Z just obtained.

$$Z^{types} = Z(a, a^2, a^3, a^4; \ o,o^2,...,o^5; \ b,b^2,...,b^6)  $$

is the type indicator polynomial. The coefficient of $a^4o^5b^6$ in $Z^{types}$ is $5808$ and it represents the number of types of partitioning the 15 mixed fruits in four nonempty baskets.

**6)** By repeating the above for 3,2, and one nonempty bucket we get

$$ 5808 + 1383 + 104 + 1 = 7296 $$

**7)**

$$Z^{egf} = Z(a, 0, 0,0; \ o,0,...,0; \ b,0,...0)  $$

is the e.g.f polynomial. The coefficient of  ${a^4\over 4!}{o^5\over 5!}{b^6\over 6!} = 42355950$  in $Z^{egf}$ represents the different distributions of 4+5+6 labelled fruits in four baskets.

**8)** by considering the other cases of non-empty baskets, one has :

$$ 42355950 + 2375101 + 16383 + 1 = 44747435$$

**9)** we may do some double check. For example, 1+104 = 105 means to distribute 5 oranges in two baskets in three ways : 5+0, 4+1, 3+2; then the apples and bananas multiplies the number of cases to 3.5.7= 105.

**10)** the $42355950$ may be obtained faster by taking the coefficient of $x^{15}$ in

$$ {1\over4!} (x + {1\over 2!}x^2 + \cdots + {1\over 15!}x^{15})^4  $$

Indeed, when distributing labelled fruits, the colouring does not matter. Whatever comnposition of a total of 15 labelled apples, oranges and bananas will produce the same number of cases.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of numbers rather than Stars and Bars, because the baskets are indistinguishable. For example, $4$ apples can be placed (partitioned) into $4$ baskets in $5$ ways:
$$\{4,0,0,0\},\{3,1,0,0\},\{2,2,0,0\},\{2,1,1,0\},\{1,1,1,1\},$$
while Stars and Bars method considers $\{4,0,0,0\}$ and $\{0,4,0,0\}$ as different choices.

With partioning of $5$ and $6$ you must be careful: $p(5)=7$ and $p(6)=11$. However, you must exclude $\{1,1,1,1,1\}$ from $p(5)$ and $\{1,1,1,1,1,1\},\{2,1,1,1,1\}$ from $p(6)$, because there are only $4$ baskets (numbers).

Hence, the final answer is:

> $5\cdot 6\cdot 9=270.$